# Displaying a decimal Format for Euros

Tags: java, decimalformat, euro

I want the price to be in Euros €, what do i need to change with the code below?

I have it in dollars so far

```
DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat( "$0.00" );
```

Comment: DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat( "€0.00" );

Comment: That it? because i will need to change the dollar word as there is more code to be added beneath this line of code above. e.g. (dollars.format)

Comment: Actually i think i have it now, never mind, thanks

Comment: Be careful here, most European countries use , as the decimal separator. May not be relevant here.

Comment: Ill keep an eye on it thanks

Comment: Also irrelevant but can be useful for people with the same issue.
The Euro symbol goes after the amount, like this : 0,00€

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless, I'm missing something; you could change this

```
DecimalFormat dollars = new DecimalFormat( "$0.00" );
```

to

```
DecimalFormat euros = new DecimalFormat( "€0.00" );  // <-- euros not dollars.
```

Comment: Yeah i have changed the rest of my code to Euros, no errors showing so thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can even do it this way

```
Locale italian = new Locale("it", "IT", "EURO");
Locale.setDefault(italian);
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(nf.format(123));
```

Comment: Noted for future reference! ;)